# Selection method for records that can be shown in more than one group

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i have created a crystal report using CR-2008. it is for get details of PC-shutdown down times.i want divide shutdown  time into 4 group.(Ex. like this 12AM-6AM, 6AM-12PM, 12PM-18PM and 18-12AM). it is working fine. but each recode only shown in one group. but in my table some recodes are owned to more than 2 groups. how do i show that recodes in both groups.

```
IF Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) >= time(00,00,00) and Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) < time(06,00,00) then
"12AM - 6AM"

else IF Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) >= time(06,00,00) and Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) < time(12,00,00) then
"6AM -12PM"


else IF Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) >= time(12,00,00) and Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) < time(18,00,00) then
"12PM - 6PM"


else IF Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) >= time(18,00,00) and Time({PCTIme.ShutT}) < time(23,59,59) then
"6PM - 12AM"
```

Comment: what do you mean by each record in more than one group?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table called TIME_SLOT with a START_HOUR column and 4 rows:

00am
06am
12pm
18pm

Join that table with the DOWN_TIME table using the logic that:

```
TIME_SLOT.Start_Hour >= @DOWN_TIME_Start_Hour AND
TIME_Slot.Start_Hour < @DOWN_TIME_End_Hour
```

This would cause each DOWN_TIME record to join to as many time slots that fall withing its span.